# How to use <Code> in an Astro project without getting: "Astro components cannot be rendered directly via function call"

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I am trying to use the Code element from astro's `'astro/components'` but I keep getting a `Astro components cannot be rendered directly via function call` error message
The code for the component is:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Code } from 'astro/components';

function CodeViewer() {
    const [codeToPresent, setCodeToPresent] = useState('');
    return (
        <Code code={`const foo = 'bar';`} lang="js" />
    )
}

export default CodeViewer;
```

and I am importing it like this:

```js
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
import CodeViewer from '../components/CodeViewer.jsx'
---
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I render Astro components the right way using React?

Answer (score 3):

You [cannot use an Astro component inside a React component](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#can-i-use-astro-components-inside-my-framework-components) like this.

You can pass an Astro component to a React component via a slot, which means the React component receives the rendered code as its `children` prop:

```
---
import CodeViewer from '../components/CodeViewer.jsx'
import { Code } from 'astro/components';
---

<CodeViewer>
  <Code code={`const foo = 'bar';`} lang="js" />
</CodeViewer>
```

From your code sample it looks like you may be wanting to use interactive state on the client. If that state should change the `<Code>` props, that won’t work, because Astro components are rendered entirely on the server and can’t re-render in the browser like a React component can.

Comment: hey @swithinbank can you give an example with how an Astro component can be used inside React component? thanks!